# Attachment is blank when sent first time but has data when sent second time through Apex contoller - SFDC NPSP

Tags: pdf, salesforce, email-attachments, visualforce, apex

I am working on a requirement where I have to send pdf as an attachment through Apex class in SFDC **NPSP**. So following is my program structure –

> VisualForcePage1 has two inputs – input1 and input2. The page also has
>   3 buttons – Preview, Send Email and Cancel. Depending on values of
>   input1 and input2, ApexClass1 computes values for say output1,
>   output2, output3, output4 and output5 using method getOutputMethod().
>   Values of these output1...5 variables are stored in a custom object
>   say Custom_Object__c.

```
public void getOutputMethod() {  
   // calculate values of output1...5  
   // store these values in Custom_Object__c  
}
```

When user clicks on Preview button, method previewPDF() is called, which in turn calls getOutputMethod(). Output variables (output1...5) are stored in Custom_Object__c and then control is redirected to VisualForcePage2 which has attribute renderAs = ‘pdf’.  The generated pdf has accurate data.

When user clicks on Send Email button, method emailPDF() is called, which in turn calls getOutputMethod(). Output variables (output1...5) are stored in Custom_Object__c. **However attachment pdf sent in the mail has no data first time**. For the same input values, attachment pdf has data when Send Email button is hit second and subsequent trials. Following is the code snippet for sending pdf as email –

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
// Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID  
PageReference pdf =  Page.VisualForcePage2;                         
pdf.getParameters().put('paramater1',input1);   
pdf.getParameters().put('paramater2',input2);            
pdf.setRedirect(true);    
// Take the PDF content    
Blob b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();               
// Create the email attachment    
String filename = 'myPage.pdf';   
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();  
efa.setFileName(filename);  
efa.setBody(b);                 
// Sets the paramaters of the email    
String subject = 'Subject';                                                
body = 'Hello';              
email.setSubject(subject);  
email.setToAddresses('example@email.com');  
email.setPlainTextBody(body);    
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});     
// Sends the email
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

> ApexClass2 of VisualForcePage2 queries Custom_Object__c with input1
>   and input2 as parameters as below –

```
public ApexClass2() {  // constructor  
    var1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('paramater1');  
    var2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('paramater2');               getCustomObject();   
}      

public List<Custom_Object__c> getCustomObject() {  
    List<Custom_Object__c> coList = new List<Custom_Object__c>([
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5  
FROM Custom_Object__c
WHERE  field1 =: var1
AND    field2 =: var2 ]);     
    return coList;                                                                                         
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. The code which was sending the attachment was picking up the records from database before they were updated. Hence, it was picking either blank or old data.

I added `@future(callout=true)` at the start of the method responsible for send attachment mail.